# Failed to fetch updates

Tags: apt, permissions, updates

I am running into an issue when trying to run `apt update` on 19.10. I am getting the following error:

```
E: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata is not (yet) available (Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_eoan-security_multiverse_cnf_Commands-amd64.xz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80])
```

I checked that file and it is owned by root with 644 permissions.

Any pointers?

### EDIT

I am running this as root, for those who asked.

Comment: Yes, I am running as root.

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error due to lack of priviledge or if you run it as a non root user.

You need to use `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update`. This will ask you to enter an associated sudoers password.

Comment: Running as non-root fails way earlier than this. This is the error I get when running as root.